# How to get the timezone and change the screen color according to the hour on android

Tags: android

I want to create an android app that gets the timezone and the time of the device and sets the colour of the screen based on the hour,
**Example**: white at noon and black at midnight, I searched how to do this but I could not find any code that shows how to do something similar to this but without the fire.

[The fire animation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj10ZyV8-vhAhUI-6QKHecCCfQQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgfycat.com%252Fhandmadeevenhuemul%26psig%3DAOvVaw3lENWZ407y7_jQ7THJelxa%26ust%3D1556304220697651&psig=AOvVaw3lENWZ407y7_jQ7THJelxa&ust=1556304220697651)

What libraries should i use to get the hour and to link it with the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what you want to achieve exactly , but if you want to change the color according to time :

```
//Get the device time hour and minute

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//24
int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);//59
```

after you have the hour an minute value , you can change the background of your layout with the color you want with the statement you want , example : when its night

```
if(hrs>20 && hrs < 3){
Layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color));
}
```

Comment: What happens when user manually change the time? what will happen?

Comment: the time in the app will change also , because you get the time from the device

Comment: Is there any way to make sure that user has not changed the time?

Comment: i dont know what you mean , but if you want to use real time not from device , you can use time from internet